# How to build select count(*) and group by SQL query with Hibernate's CriteriaBuilder?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have the following code in my repository class:

```
Root<Post> fromPost = query.from(Post.class);
Selection<Long> longSelection = criteriaBuilder.count(fromPost).alias("c");
Selection<Object> item = fromPost.get("creatorId").alias("item");
CriteriaQuery<GroupEntry> select = query.multiselect(longSelection, item);
select.groupBy(fromPost.get("creatorId"));
select.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(criteriaBuilder.count(fromPost)));
```

Here I'm trying to build a query using CriteriaBuilder like this:

```
select count(*), creator_id from post 
group by creator_id
order by count(*) desc
```

However, Hibernate generates not `count(*)`, but `count(post.post_id)` in both `select` and `group by` statements. The first one is significantly faster than second one in given situation, because it doesn't use database heap, but indexes only - unlike `count(field)`.

Some additional details:

- PostgreSQL 9.6
- Hibernate 4.3.10
- My `Post` class looks like this:

  ```
  import javax.persistence.*;   

  @Entity
  @Table(name = "post")
  public class Post implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "post_id", updatable = false)
  protected String postId;

  other fields...
  }
  ```
- `GroupEntry` class contains `id`, `c` and `item` columns.

Comment: I assume post.post_id is the primary key and then the primary should have an index too. So no issue IMHO